# ERROR: from solidity:ParserError: Expected identifier but got '('. Occurs whenever I add the line described below

Tags: solidity, remix, ether

I am working on creating a smart contract with a random mint function. The solidity compiler keeps spitting out the following error: from solidity:ParserError: Expected identifier but got '(', every time I add the RandomlyAssigned function to the constructor that will let me randomly assign 200 NFT's to myself at the start of contract execution.

I am using a combination of the HashLipz NFT contract (no issues on it's own) and the WeMint Washington (We Mint Cash) Random Mint NFT Contracts (also no issue on it's own).

Below is my line of code:

```
    `constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    string memory _initBaseURI,
    string memory _initNotRevealedUri
  )



ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    setNotRevealedURI(_initNotRevealedUri);
  }



RandomlyAssigned(5000,200) { **Error Appears on this Line**
        for (uint256 a = 1; a <= 200; a++) {
            mint(msg.sender);
        }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: ```RandomlyAssigned(5000,200) { **Error Appears on this Line**
        for (uint256 a = 1; a <= 200; a++) {
            mint(msg.sender);
        }
```
You're creating new function in above line?

Answer (score 0):

Create function like this:

```
function RandomlyAssigned(uint256 amount,uint256 num) { **No more error on this Line**
        for (uint256 a = 1; a <= num; a++) {  // is this loop really needed?
            mint(msg.sender, amount);  // mint function takes amount as 2nd argument to mint
        }
}
```

Then call in constructor as:

```
constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    string memory _initBaseURI,
    string memory _initNotRevealedUri
  ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    setNotRevealedURI(_initNotRevealedUri);
    RandomlyAssigned(5000,200);
  }
```